# SharePoint list open in access

Tags: list, microsoft-access

I have a SharePoint list that I'm connecting to Access for editing.

All of the single line of text fields show up but the choice fields do not, these are not multiple choice just single choice fields.

Is there a limitation with opening a list in Access supporting choice fields?

Comment: Are you getting any errors when you attempt to link them? The only limitation I know of is the number of columns allowed (ie 256). https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Synchronize-a-SharePoint-2010-list-with-Access-2010-975bfb97-c799-4fce-b7cc-3db3b397f116?CorrelationId=f04d0e5d-26c5-4e0b-8633-cd218b6f4fa9&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: No errors when I open the list I created in access. It simply doesn't show the values for choice fields even though in the list they are populated. In access they show up blank.